GA4 event parameter not in list when creating custom dimension
I've created a custom event with two parameters, one of them being action. I can see the event in the Events report in GA, and I can see the action parameter in real time reports, so it's getting there ok.
However when I go to create a custom dimension so that I can see the parameter in an exploration (or whatever the custom reports are called) it's not in the list.
I've done it before for another event and as far as I can tell I've followed the same steps, so I don't understand how action just isn't there.
To illustrate the point here's the original one with the action parameter in place:

And the one I'm trying to build that has nothing above batch_ordering_id:


It may take up to two days. If you saw it in real time, it will appear here soon.
